# How can I replace [0] with ascending numbers in a text file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I want to change a file with text like this

```
Application[0]=test_app1
Application[0]=test_aap2
Application[0]=test_app3
Application[0]=test_app4
..
```

to have ascending numbers like this:

```
Application[0]=test_app1
Application[1]=test_aap2
Application[2]=test_app3
Application[3]=test_app4
..
```

Comment: welcome to ask ubuntu, please provide more information about what you are trying to do and what you have tried. the information that is currently in this post makes it hard to answer. Are you trying to do this with a bash script or some other language?

Comment: Close voters: this is not in the least off-topic or unclear. It is a question about text processing with an input sample, the desired output for the same sample, and a logical description of the change (replace 0 with ascending numbers).

Answer (score 6):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/\[0\]/"[" . $i++ . "]"/e' < input
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and returns each after processing
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` replaces the pattern by the replacement. Square brackets in the pattern must be escaped to match literally, as they have a special meaning otherwise.
- `/e` evaluates the replacement as code, so `$i++` increments `$i` and `.` concatenates the result to the square brackets